# Get all cells in collectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

How can I get all cells in `collectionView`?
The `collectionView` only has a method `indexForVisibleItem` and I can only select the cells which appears in the screen but I can't access the invisible cells. For example I have 50 images in `collectionView` when I try to use the `indexForVisibleItem` method I get only 24 images. How can I select all cells 50 images in `CollectionView`? Any way can I perform this task?

my code:

```
@IBAction func selectAllActionBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    dictionaryOfImagesForExport = [:]
    dictionaryOfGetImageUrl = [:]
    if editing {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    do {
        let document = try fileManager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)

        let getFolders = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(document, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles)

        for folder in getFolders {
            if folder.lastPathComponent! == albumName {
                let getImages = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(folder, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles)
                for index in 0...getImages.count {
                    let indexP = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)
                   let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexP) as! AlbumImagesCollectionViewCell

                    for img in getImages {
                        cell.imageViewCell.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: img)!)


                        cell.imageViewCheck.image = UIImage(named: "check.png")
                        dictionaryOfImagesForExport.updateValue(cell.imageViewCell.image!, forKey: indexP.row)
                        dictionaryOfGetImageUrl.updateValue(cell.imageUrlLabel.text!, forKey: indexP.row)
                    }


                }
            }
        }

    }catch {
        print(error)
    }

        exportBtn.enabled = true
        moveBtn.enabled = true
        deleteBtn.enabled = true
    }


}
```

thanks advance

Comment: no - the cells don't actually exist. what are you actually trying to achieve, why do you need the cells anyway? just to mark them all as selected? also never call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` outside the collection delegate function...

Comment: i need to make buttons select all i have app photo vault i need to take the user ability to can select all images(get contents all cells (Images)) for do some task like delete all images in any albums how can i achieve this task ?

Comment: check this link might be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916900/selecting-all-the-items-in-uicollectionview-ios-even-the-cells-that-are-not-vis

Comment: thank you very much i will check it

Comment: the code in the link not work ? have you another way for perform this  task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your collectionView dislay 24 cells , it means there are only 24 cells in the collection view.

If you want check all, i think you should implement the cell mode as the following

```
class cellMode{
  ......
  var status = false
  ......
}
```

Change the status of cells and reload collectionview, when select/deselect all.

Comment: Thank you very much , can you give me example