# How to select all UICollectionView Cell's and Deselect by button click?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, jquery-ui-selectable

I need realize some filer with over 15 buttons as filter tabs,
I added horizontal CollectionView, custom Cell, two array’s.
Single selection works well,
but I need select all and deselect all by button click 
any idea how to realize it?

[Selecting all the items in UICollectionView iOS, even the cells that are not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916900/selecting-all-the-items-in-uicollectionview-ios-even-the-cells-that-are-not-vis)

this one doesn't work

```swift
 var arraySelectedFilterIndex = [IndexPath]()
 var arraySelectedFilterData = [String]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.filterTitles.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FilterCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterCell

        cell.titleL.text = String(filterTitles[indexPath.row])
        cell.pointIMG.image = UIImage(named: filterTitles[indexPath.row] + "40")

        if arraySelectedFilterIndex.contains(indexPath) { // You need to check wether selected index array contain current index if yes then change the color
            cell.isSelected = true
        }
        else {
            cell.isSelected = false
        }

        cell.layoutSubviews()
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
        Haptico.shared().generate(.light)

        let strData = filterTitles[indexPath.item]

        if arraySelectedFilterIndex.contains(indexPath) {
            arraySelectedFilterIndex = arraySelectedFilterIndex.filter { $0 != indexPath}
            arraySelectedFilterData = arraySelectedFilterData.filter { $0 != strData}
        }
        else {
            arraySelectedFilterIndex.append(indexPath)
            arraySelectedFilterData.append(strData)
        }
        collectionView.reloadData()
        print(arraySelectedFilterData)
    }

@IBAction func selectAllA(_ sender: Any) {. 

//here need add code with All Select and Deselect functions

}
```

Comment: Is there any other state other than `all selected` & `all deselected` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why sometimes you use "indexPath.row" and sometimes "indexPath.item".

Regardless, your function should look something like this

```
@IBAction func selectAllA(_ sender: Any) {
        arraySelectedFilterIndex.removeAll()
        arraySelectedFilterData.removeAll()

        for (index, element) in self.filterTitles.enumerated() {
            arraySelectedFilterIndex.append(IndexPath(item: index, section: 0))
            arraySelectedFilterData.append(element)
        }

        collectionView.reloadData()
        print(arraySelectedFilterData)
    }
```

At first you are clearing previous selections to avoid duplicates, you could use a map/dictionary structure to avoid duplicated instead of a list though.

Then for each element you add the index and data to the selected list. Finally reload the data, I kept you the print at the end so you can check it.